# Code to compare 2 CSV files doesn't see similarities

Tags: java, csv, compare, java.util.scanner

Code to compare 2 CSV files:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class compareCSV {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int j = 0;
        int countLinesInW = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("src/hurtownie/file1.csv"));
        Scanner w = new Scanner(new File("src/hurtownie/file2.csv"));
        while (w.hasNextLine()) {
            String lineW = w.nextLine();
            countLinesInW++;
        while(s.hasNextLine()) {
            String lineS = s.nextLine();
            if(lineS.equals(lineW)){
                j++;
            }
        }
        }
        System.out.println(countLinesInW);
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

In file1 I have one column with 3000 rows. 
In file2 I have one column with 1000 rows.
`countLinesInW` is only counter to rows and work correctly.
Problem exist for `j` counter. It should check amount of a same lines, but it doesn't correctly. `j` return "1", but I know it is so low (expected result ~700).

Comment: it's better to include some lines of your csv files in the above question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code

```
while (w.hasNextLine()) {
    String lineW = w.nextLine();
    countLinesInW++;
    while(s.hasNextLine()) {
        String lineS = s.nextLine();
        if(lineS.equals(lineW)){
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

s.hasNextLine() is always false, after the scanner w has finished reading the whole file once.

Is your aim to get the number of similar lines from both csv files, I would suggest reading all the lines and saving them first in two lists, and then compare the two 
lists to get the number of similar lines. Something like

```
List<String> linesInFile1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> linesInFile2 = new ArrayList<>();
while (w.hasNextLine()) {
    String lineW = w.nextLine();
    linesInFile1.add(lineW);
}
while(s.hasNextLine()) {
    String lineS = s.nextLine();
    linesInFile2.add(lineS);
}

linesInFile1.retainAll(linesInFile2);
j = linesInFile1.size();
```

Note that retainAll method retains the common items in both lists.

Answer (score 1):

No direct loop needed and possible to specify character set if needed:

```
List<String> linesInFile1 = Files.readAllLines(new File("file1.csv").toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset() );
List<String> linesInFile2 = Files.readAllLines(new File("file2.csv").toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset() );

linesInFile1.retainAll(linesInFile2);
```